# destructure object if value of some key is possibly null

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am destructuring an object in `map` function, object might contain value `null` for some keys of object. it is something like below:

```
{key1, key2} = {key1 : null,key2:'someval'}
```

I am seeing error saying key1 is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable using `let` or `var` like `var {key1, key2}`

```js
var {key1, key2} = {key1 : null,key2:'someval'};
console.log(key1);
console.log(key2);
```

Using `{key1, key2}` will give you that error:

```js
{key1, key2}
```

Comment: I am doing the destructuring in map function, in which the passed function will get an object as defined above. So this will not work in that.

Answer (score 0):

Without (or earlier) declaring and direct assignment, you need parentheses around the expression for destructuring to distinguish the objects brackets from a block statement.

```js
({ key1, key2 } = { key1: null, key2: 'someval'});

console.log(key1, key2);
```

Comment: I am using this in map function's callback like ({key1, key2})=>console.log(ke1, key2))

Comment: please add the whole code, you tried, to the question.